# What days will I be able to read on the train?

Tags: persona-5

Some days, I am able to find a seat on the train and get some reading done. Unfortunately, there have been a few days where I didn't happen to have any unfinished books on me and the time was wasted. I assume that these days are static and everyone is able to read on the train on specific days of the year.

If this is true, what days should I have a book handy so I can read on the train?

Comment: I would assume it is static but I do not know that for sure since it would be kind of difficult to test thoroughly. Too bad your character couldn't just get some audiobooks so you could always "read" on the train.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more searching, it appears that a list of days you're able to read on the train can be found [here](http://gearnuke.com/persona-5-guide-find-read-books/):

> To read them, you can also spend some time reading them during the following specific dates, when you manage to sit in a train on your way to school:
>
> - 4/20
> - 4/25
> - 4/30
> - 5/21
> - 5/24
> - 5/30
> - 6/3
> - 6/15
> - 6/23
> - 7/1
> - 7/4
> - 7/8
> - 9/24
> - 9/28
> - 10/6
> - 11/2
> - 11/5
> - 11/10
> - 11/14
> - 11/17

I have not progressed nearly as far into the game as this list goes, so I cannot confirm all of these yet, but I will keep tabs on this as I continue.